# `stack bench` vs `stack build mypackage:bench`

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Why does

`stack bench` builds (and run)

and

`stack build mypackage:bench` tells me

> Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_3.4.1.0_ghc-9.0.2: No benchmarks enabled. Did
> you remember to configure with '--enable-benchmarks'?

Comment: This seems like a bug with stack. I would suggest you open an issue here: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues

Comment: @Noughtmare I don't think so. cabal needs some "special thing" for building benchmarks. `stack bench` adds it, thus it works. `stack build mypackage:bench` tries to build the component like any other. I need to add some special stuff to make cabal happy but who knows why...

Comment: Stack itself should add those options for you, there should be no need for users to know anything about cabal if they use stack. (At least that is what I believe in)

Comment: yes, and that's what it does. if I run `stack bench` that's ok. I just wonder what kind of invocation I would need to add to make cabal happy through the command to build "regular" components. I am curious what options cabal requires to be happy in that case